# Cassandra Data Modeling - Design Concept

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql

I am new to Cassandra, trying to understand the concepts. Please help me :
Here I have data of citizens with their language and state.

```
create table citizens_by_state_and_language(
 citizenID BigInt,
 state varchar,
 language varchar
 primary key((language,state), citizenID)
);
```

I can query like this

```
Select * from citizens_by_state_and_language where language = 'Spanish' and state = 'Kentucky'
```

However these queries wont work:

```
Select * from citizens_by_state_and_language where language = 'Spanish';
Select * from citizens_by_state_and_language where state = 'Kentucky';
```

Now to make it working I can create indexes on these, like below:

```
create index on citizens_by_state_and_language(language);
create index on citizens_by_state_and_language(state);
```

I am not sure whether this is the right approach in designing it or Should I create separate tables(one query per table) for each of these queries?. Please throw some lights with concepts.

Answer (score 0):

That is because language and state are partition keys.

In Cassandra you can't query on a single partition key, you have to specify both of the fields to do so, that is why your first query work.

Cassandra keys are not so easy to understand, [this article](http://intellidzine.blogspot.fr/2014/01/cassandra-data-modelling-primary-keys.html) explains what's behind all those keys and [this one](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/we-shall-have-order/) is a good example.